# Capacitor: Adding IOS Entitlements without using Xcode

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm working on an iOS app created using Capacitor and Ionic. I've built my iOS app and have manually submitted it to Apple Store / TestFlight via xcode, but during that process I had to manually add an entitlement to my app. The process in the [Capacitor docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/configuration#setting-capabilities), where you edit the app entitlements in xcode, worked just fine for me. However, I would ideally like to not keep my full iOS app in source control, and as such, I would like to add my entitlements via something like the `capacitor.config.json` file.

so: Is it possible to set the iOS app entitlements via the `capacitor.config.json` file? Something like:

```json
{
    "appId": "com.app.name",
    "appName": "app name",
    "bundledWebRuntime": false,
    "cordova":
    {
        "android":
        {
            ...
        },
        "ios":
        {
            "entitlements":{
                ...
            }
            "preferences":
            {
                ...
            }
        },
        "preferences":
        {
            ...
        }
    },
    "npmClient": "npm"
}
```

If it's not, is this something that I can edit in my ci pipeline, like the android or iOS app version? I'm using a script to set the version in the android manifest / ios info.plist in my azure build pipeline. I would assume editing the  `AppRelease.entitlements` file would work pretty similarly, being an xml file.

Ionic / Cap Versions:

```
> ionic info

   Ionic:

   Ionic CLI       : 6.16.3 
   Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 4.11.13

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/android : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/core    : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/ios     : 2.4.7

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   NodeJS : v12.16.1 
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : macOS Big Sur
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have done that in the past is by using `xcodebuild` with an `exportOptionsRelease.plist` file.

```sh
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath Release.xcarchive -exportPath Release -exportOptionsPlist exportOptionsRelease.plist
```

You should also probably consider keeping the iOS project in source control. Might save you headaches later. Capacitor even [recommends it](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova#native-project-management).

Comment: My team had some exciting merge adventures with our ios app specifically in the past, so I'm willing to keep it in source control, but want to avoid it if possible. :) 

Thanks for the tip on the exportOptionsRelease plist, i'll try that out!